# How to disable individual items in ChoiceBox?

Tags: java, javafx

How can I disable individual items in a JavaFX `ChoiceBox`?
I don't want to disable the complete `ChoiceBox` like this:

```java
choiceBox.setDisable(true);
```

Comment: Not sure you can for a `ChoiceBox`. Or at least, I'm not sure this can be accomplished easily. If you were using a `ComboBox` instead, then you could set the `cellFactory` which returns a custom cell implementation, and from there you could disable any cells as needed.

Comment: You can remove items from the choice list, that is not the same as disabling though.

Answer (score 4):

There is no public API for disabling items in ChoiceBox.  As suggested in the comments you can use a ComboBox instead.

The solution uses an [extractor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList(java.util.List,javafx.util.Callback)) on a model property (in this case a todo task completed boolean property) to determine whether an item in the combo box should be disabled.

**Example Usage**

No tasks are completed, and "Feed the cat" task is selected from the drop-down.

[image: all enabled]

The "Complete" button has been pressed to complete the "Feed the cat" task, which remains selected but is shown disabled.

[image: feed the cat disabled]

The drop-down is shown, and the disabled "Feed the cat" task is still selected.

[image: feed the cat disabled and dropped down]

The "Mow the lawn" task is selected.  The "Feed the cat" task remains disabled and can no longer be selected again.

[image: mow the lawn selected]

**Example Implementation**

I manually set the opacity for the disabled items.  Usually, that would occur automatically, but some quirk of the ComboBox styling doesn't persist the styling for the disabled opacity without manually overriding it (from my testing).

The factory which generates the cells is configurable.  I have used the standard feedback for disabled items of setting the opacity to visually indicate they are disabled.  But you could provide a different implementation (e.g for a todo list, you could provide a check mark against or strike-through of completed tasks that can no longer be selected).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class TodoComboBoxApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<ToDoItem> todoList = FXCollections.observableList(
                List.of(
                        new ToDoItem("Weed the garden"),
                        new ToDoItem("Mow the lawn"),
                        new ToDoItem("Feed the cat"),
                        new ToDoItem("Feed the fish"),
                        new ToDoItem("Feed the fish to the cat")
                ),
                todoItem -> new Observable[] { todoItem.completeProperty() }
        );

        ComboBox<ToDoItem> taskComboBox = new ComboBox<>(todoList);
        taskComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        taskComboBox.setCellFactory(param -> new ToDoCell());
        taskComboBox.setButtonCell(new ToDoCell());

        Button completeButton = new Button("Complete");
        completeButton.setOnAction(e ->
                taskComboBox
                        .getSelectionModel()
                        .getSelectedItem()
                        .setComplete(true)
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(20, completeButton, taskComboBox);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}

class ToDoItem {
    private final String taskName;
    private final BooleanProperty complete = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    ToDoItem(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }

    public String getTaskName() {
        return taskName;
    }

    public boolean isComplete() {
        return complete.get();
    }

    public void setComplete(boolean complete) {
        this.complete.set(complete);
    }

    public BooleanProperty completeProperty() {
        return complete;
    }
}

class ToDoCell extends ListCell<ToDoItem> {
    ToDoCell() {
        disabledProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                setOpacity(newValue != null && newValue ? .6 : 1)
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(ToDoItem item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
            setDisable(false);
            return;
        }

        setText(item.getTaskName());
        setDisable(item.isComplete());

        System.out.println(item.getTaskName() + ", disabled? " + isDisabled());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can avoid the extractor by binding Disable of the ToDoCell directly to item.completeProperty.  And you can avoid the Listener by binding ToDoCell.opacity to ToDoCell.Disabled.

Comment: @DaveB yes, I originally used binding, but I preferred the extractor, so I went with that. With binding you need to unbind and rebind whenever the item backing the cell changes.  With the extractor, the updateItem code is straight forward.

Comment: I don't see it.  Now the ComboBox's operation is dependent on the structure of the external element, the list.  A simple disableProperty().unbind() right after super.updateItem() and then everything is self-contained.

Comment: @DaveB either solution is valid, if you prefer binding over an extractor, then use that.

Comment: The items in ```List.of()``` don't want to load. I copied it 1:1.

Comment: @query perhaps you are using obsolete Java and JavaFX versions.  [`List.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) functionality was added in Java 9.

Comment: I'm using the JDK 17.0.3 and Java SDK 8 Update 301

Comment: @query That is not possible.  You can't be using both JDK 17 and JDK 8.  You can only use one JDK version at a time.  You should be using the most recent stable software versions, JDK 18+ and JavaFX 18+.  You should not be using obsolete versions of the JDK and JavaFX, such as are provided in JDK 8.

Comment: The ComboBox is still empty.

Comment: I don’t have further advice, this works for me using the software versions mentioned.